Integral of $\frac{\log x}{(1-x)^2}$
We need to evaluate the improper integral
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\log x}{(1-x)^2}dx
$$
I tried several things a direct comparison, a comparison with $y=\log x$ as an substitution, but I can’t get it to work, and the only hint from the question is, that it doesn’t converge.

Near $x=1$ we have $\log x \sim x-1$, so $$\frac{\log x}{(1-x)^2} \sim \frac{1}{x-1}$$ so the integral doesn't converge.

There is an elementary closed form antiderivative.  Integration by parts with the choice
$$u = \log x, \quad du = \frac{1}{x} \, dx, \\ dv = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} \, dx, \quad v = \frac{1}{1-x},$$
yields
$$\int \frac{\log x}{(1-x)^2} \, dx = \frac{\log x}{1-x} - \int \frac{1}{x(1-x)} \, dx.$$  The remaining integral is amenable to partial fraction decomposition:
$$\int \frac{1}{x(1-x)} \, dx = \int \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x-1} \, dx = \log x - \log (x-1) + C = \log \frac{x}{x-1} +C.$$
Therefore,
$$I(x) = \int \frac{\log x}{(1-x)^2} \, dx = \frac{\log x}{1-x} - \log \frac{x}{x-1} + C.$$
However, the definite integral does not converge:  while
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} I(x) = 0,$$ unfortunately,
$$\lim_{x \to 1^-} I(x) = -\infty.$$

Commenting to send a message: A visitor has asked about getting alternative views of some tessellated tori shown in an old Mathematica.SE post of yours. Perhaps you'd like to respond. (I'll delete this message later.)
